# why sqrt times cos return wrong value

Tags: java, math, sqrt, trigonometry

I am coding a calculater that find the coordinates of a rotated point. (inspired from math tutorial on youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQduSvpTyhs)

the part where im stuck is the return of ansx and ansy. instead of 4.0 and 3.6 it returns incorect answer. (Nouvelles coordoner : -3.0853888289108733,-4.413657867849748)

I cant understand what is happening wrong in those 2 lines ...

```
static void tourner()
    {
        Scanner tournsc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double coordx, coordy, roattiondeg, ansx, ansy, angle, triangleh, newangle;
        //Test input : X 5, Y 2, rotation deg 20
        System.out.println("Coord X :");
        coordx = tournsc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Coord Y :");
        coordy = tournsc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Degre : ");
        roattiondeg = tournsc.nextInt();

        triangleh = ((Math.pow(coordx, 2)) + (Math.pow(coordy, 2)));

        angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(coordy/coordx));
        newangle = roattiondeg + angle;
        ansx = Math.sqrt(triangleh)*Math.cos(newangle);
        ansy = Math.sqrt(triangleh)*Math.sin(newangle);
        System.out.println("Nouvelles coordoner : " + ansx + "," + ansy);


    }
```

Question : why ansx and ansy give good answer on my real life calculater but wrong in the program?

thx for helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library functions `sin` and `cos` expect their input to be in radians but you passed them degrees instead.

Just keep it all in radians from the input onwards and you shouldn't have a problem:

```
    roattiondeg = Math.toRadians(tournsc.nextInt());

    triangleh = ((Math.pow(coordx, 2)) + (Math.pow(coordy, 2)));

    angle = Math.atan(coordy/coordx));
    newangle = roattiondeg + angle;
    ansx = Math.sqrt(triangleh)*Math.cos(newangle);
    ansy = Math.sqrt(triangleh)*Math.sin(newangle);
    System.out.println("Nouvelles coordoner : " + ansx + "," + ansy);
```